# Performing UNION select getting which table the data come from

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables which share the exact same structure, like:

```
id       name_col
```

I have this query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_1 UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_2 UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_3");
```

Now:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    names .= $row['name_col'];
    // HERE HOW I COULD KNOW WHICH TABLE THIS DATA IS COMING FROM?
    // THIS NAME IS FROM tbl_1 OR tbl_2 OR tbl_3
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a constant field to your subqueries in order to index them, as follow:

SQL:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS tbl ROM tbl_1 
UNION
SELECT *, 2 AS tbl FROM tbl_2 
UNION
SELECT *, 3 AS tbl FROM tbl_3
```

The column name for that extra field must be consistent accross the subqueries.

PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    names .= $row['name_col'];
    switch ($row['tbl']){
         case 1: // tbl_1
         break;
         // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can additionally add a custom column which specifies the name of the table where it belongs, eg

```
SELECT id, name_col, 'table1' tableName FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, name_col, 'table2' tableName FROM table2
UNION
SELECT id, name_col, 'table3' tableName FROM table3
```

Comment: Would you please also add an example in mysql_fetch_array()? thanks

Comment: there are bunch of example on this [link: mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)